# Is there a way to retrieve values from the passed-in Modifier?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I create a composable with a Modifier as a parameter. Although I do not think that this would be possible, but is there anyway a method by which I can retrieve the values passed in to this modifier?

```
{
 mComp(Modifier.height(100.dp).width(100.dp))
}

@Composable
fun mComp(modifier: Modifier){ // Yeah I know Composable names should start with a Cap Letter
 //Retrieve the height and width here. How?
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible and it is intentional. For instance, in a coroutine `flow` you can't query in the collector whether a `filter` was applied or not, it's opaque, and the same applies to modifiers. If you want to retrieve some argument from a modifier you can create your custom one, [this article](https://fvilarino.medium.com/creating-a-custom-modifier-attribute-on-jetpack-compose-f100c6bcb987) shows how to do so

Comment: The article seems helpful. I'll let you know. Thanks man!