# Jetpack Compose extract padding info from Modifier

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I want to extract padding(or other params if needed) information from Modifier. I need to extract padding to use `Modiifer.drawBehind` with `Layout` to draw a bubble shape behind my list of Composables. As can be seen in second bubble padding is applied but since i'm not able to get padding it doesn't cover entire layout only available area after padding is applied

[image]
[image]

```
  @Composable
    fun BubbleColumn(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        bubbleState: BubbleState,
        content: @Composable () -> Unit
    ) {
        val contentRect = remember { BubbleRect() }
        val bubbleRect = remember { BubbleRect() }
        val path = remember { Path() }
    
        val newModifier = modifier
            .materialShadow(bubbleState, path)
            .drawBehind {
                drawPath(path = path, color = bubbleState.backgroundColor)
    
                drawRect(
                    color = Color.Red,
                    topLeft = Offset(bubbleRect.left, bubbleRect.top),
                    size = Size(bubbleRect.width, bubbleRect.height),
                    style = Stroke(2f)
                )
    
                drawRect(
                    color = Color.Blue,
                    topLeft = Offset(contentRect.left, contentRect.top),
                    size = Size(contentRect.width, contentRect.height),
                    style = Stroke(2f)
                )
            }
    
        Layout(
            content = content,
            modifier = newModifier
    
        ) { measurables, constraints ->
    
            measureBubbleColumnResult(
                bubbleState = bubbleState,
                measurables = measurables,
                constraints = constraints,
                rectContent = contentRect,
                rect = bubbleRect,
                path = path
            )
        }
    }
```

Use is as

```
    BubbleColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Yellow),
        bubbleState = bubbleStateShadow1
    ) {
        Text(text = "Composable1")
        Text(text = "Composable12")
    }

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(10.dp))
    BubbleColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Green).padding(10.dp),
        bubbleState = bubbleStateShadow2
    ) {
        Text(text = "Composable1")
        Text(text = "Composable12")
    }
```

When i set padding it's for `BubbleColumn` inside layout it's not possible to get padding using `placeable` width or `Constraint`.
[Accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68725596/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-values-from-the-passed-in-modifier) for this question states there is no way to extract it but i read from a Google developer, can't find the source, it's possible with `Modifier.any`, `Modifier.foldIn` or `Modifier.oldOut` but couldn't find an answer, it didn't specify how to do so, or how to use these modifiers either.

I can create a `ParentDataModifier` or pass padding value directly for my problem but my question is not only specific for this problem, i wonder how to retrieve data from modifier itself since toString method shows some of the available parameters for `Modifier`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```kotlin
val newModifier = modifier
    .materialShadow(bubbleState, path)
    .drawBehind {
        drawPath(path = path, color = bubbleState.backgroundColor)
    
        drawRect(
            color = Color.Red,
            topLeft = Offset(bubbleRect.left, bubbleRect.top),
            size = Size(bubbleRect.width, bubbleRect.height),
            style = Stroke(2f)
        )

        drawRect(
            color = Color.Blue,
            topLeft = Offset(contentRect.left, contentRect.top),
            size = Size(contentRect.width, contentRect.height),
            style = Stroke(2f)
        )
    }
```

to

```kotlin
val newModifier = Modifier
    .materialShadow(bubbleState, path)
    .drawBehind {
        drawPath(path = path, color = bubbleState.backgroundColor)
    
        drawRect(
            color = Color.Red,
            topLeft = Offset(bubbleRect.left, bubbleRect.top),
            size = Size(bubbleRect.width, bubbleRect.height),
            style = Stroke(2f)
        )

        drawRect(
            color = Color.Blue,
            topLeft = Offset(contentRect.left, contentRect.top),
            size = Size(contentRect.width, contentRect.height),
            style = Stroke(2f)
        )
    }
    .then(modifier)
```

or set a parameter like `contentPadding` and set modifier in a proper place.

Comment: i already tried this. It didn't work since i set layout and drawBehind. You need to implement it as `Modifier.padding` does with `constrainst.offset`, and setting `placeable` position. You can see implementation [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Speech-Bubble/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/speechbubble/BubbleColumn.kt) but as i mentioned in question i did it adding padding values to `BubbleState` not able to retrieve them from `Modifier`

Comment: I apologize for posting an answer without practice. But I have another idea is to put the content into a `Box` and set the `bubbleModifier` to the `Box`, and then use `Box` or `Layout` to limit the first `Box` to the content area of ​​the bubble.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions i already did created it as [modifier](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Speech-Bubble/blob/eedbfa4c06f70ed15380d762ee5736972d49a8c0/lib/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/speechbubble/BubbleModifier.kt#L48), works with it. Point of creating my custom column was to use  optimize it since it will have a lot of dynamic stuff inside. I also fixed my `BubbleColumn` passing padding values externally. My question is not specific to this problem i wonder how it's possible to extract data from Modifier itself. I know it's possible but can't figure out how yet.

Comment: Sorry for not helping you.